# How to modify include path for a specific include

Tags: c, gcc, libxml2, libiconv

I've got an application which is using both iconv functionality and libxml2.

libxml2 is installed in `/usr/local`, so I am using the compiler flag `-I/usr/local/include`.  There is also a standalone libiconv installation in `/usr/local` which I don't want to use (I want to use the one in glibc).

Within my application code, I can sort out the iconv problem by doing:

```
#include </usr/include/iconv.h>
```

However, the problem is that the libxml2 stuff is also using iconv for it's own internal purposes.  And the libxml2 headers just do:

```
#include <iconv.h>
```

Is there any way around that?  For example can I do anything in my code where I am including the libxml headers, to tell it where to search for iconv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, include the correct `<iconv.h>` before any libxml2 headers, even in sources that don't use iconv.  This will prevent libxml headers from including any other version (assuming the header guards are the same...).

For a long-term fix, you will need to fix your system (because it is, in fact, broken).  You cannot install packages in `/usr/local` and then later expect to be able to enable or disable them individually.  Instead, install your packages with separate prefixes.  For example, install libxml2 in `/opt/libxml2`, and install iconv in `/opt/iconv`.

Comment: Yep that has worked perfectly.  I'll hopefully be able to sort out the machine config later on.  It's a shared machine, but it was me who had set it up wrongly - I copied a project from an old AIX box where the built-in iconv was woefully lacking basic character sets (e.g. UTF-8), and so built the same GNU iconv libraries to get it working on the Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `-I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include`, gcc should look in /usr/include first...except that gcc treats system headers differently, so that doesn't work.  As an ugly hack, you can copy /usr/include/iconv.h to a different directory and specify it in a -I flag before /usr/local/include.